# Is there any equivalent method in android like java main method?

Tags: android

I need clarification on this. If there is no main() method in android. Instead of it, which acts as a main() method in android. Please kindly give an explanation in detail. I'm new to android. Let me know this basic thing.

Comment: In you manifest you define which activity should act as the main entry point.

Comment: you define main launcher activity in manifest file. onCreate() method of that activity is the first method called (start point) in Android

Comment: Launcher Activity is main class to start application and method you may say onCreate method is always called when you are using Activity.

Comment: Please also look into some Android tutorials before you jump into making applications. You cannot resolve each doubt you come across over here

Answer (score 2):

The `onCreate()` method of `Application` class implementation is the entry point of your Android application where you get control over the logic part.

The `onCreate()` method of the `Launcher` `Activity` is the next point where you get control over the user flow.

Comment: This is not entirely a true analog to a C program main.  In fact, there is none for Android.

Comment: I believe the question was asking for the entry point to the application and not any technical difference/similarity

Comment: See my answer here for a full explanation why there is no true equivalent of main, and how there is an even earlier entry point than the one you suggest.

Comment: The person asking the question is a beginner. ContentProviders have a very different use case to be explained at the moment

Comment: The OP asked for an answer *in detail*.  I did that.

Comment: Please read the question again. I am not saying that you are wrong

Answer (score 0):

`Android` applications are written by `Java-LIKE` language. but the truth is `Java Virtual Machine` is not running on android devices. so there is no need to have `main()` function to appear in the code.

if you take a look at `Android Application Lifecycle` you will see that the `onCreate()` is the first stage of the cycle so you can think of it as the `main()` function of `Android`

Answer (score 0):

`main()` function is the starting point of the java application. The class you want first to be executed, you include the `main()` in that class.

In `Android`, you have to declare `Intent Filter` with `Launcher` action against the `Activity` you want to show first.

```
    <activity>
    <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

`onCreate` of this `Activity` will be called first before any other activities.

Moreover, you can also create custom `Application` object and name this application in `AndroidManifest` as

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    private static Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }
}
```

And name you application in `AndroidMAnifest` as

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:name=".MyApplication"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pure "main" method that acts as the root method for Android app.  In C, main is the entry point AND exit point, but there is no such thing for Android.

The closest alternative is `Application.onCreate()`.  However, note that each defined `ContentProvider.onCreate()` actually gets called *before* `Application.onCreate()`.  So a Content Provider is actually your first available hook into an Android process.

You define your Application class in the **manifest** [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html).  Your content providers are defined in the manifest [at this point](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html).

Answer (score 0):

In java program executes always from main method.

But in Android it depends on components lifecycle.

Activity, Fragment, Service etc have their own lifecyle.

For better understanding visit android developer site.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

And make some examples using all lifecycle methods.